# Jetty 9 fails to run on Android

Tags: android, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to use Jetty 9 on Android 4.2 but i got this exception:

```
05-20 16:27:44.230: E/dalvikvm(27558): Could not find class 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server', referenced from method com.example.jettydemoappproject.JettyMainActivity.onCreate
05-20 16:27:44.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 16:27:44.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27558): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
05-20 16:27:44.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27558): at com.example.jettydemoappproject.JettyMainActivity.onCreate(JettyMainActivity.java:36)
```

Code (JettyMainActivity.java):

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
....
public class JettyMainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jetty_main);

        Server webServer = new Server(8080);
        ....
        }
 }
```

I've added this jars to "libs" project folder (and added to Build path):

```
jetty-continuation-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
jetty-http-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
jetty-io-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
jetty-security-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
jetty-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar <-- this one contains 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server'
jetty-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
jetty-util-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
jetty-webapp-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
jetty-xml-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
servlet-api-3.0.jar
```

Removing from each one the file "about.html" (becase it's duplicate).

What i'm doing wrong? The same code works fine as a desktop application.

Comment: I am getting the same error in jetty 7.0 did u find any solution?? please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty 9.x requires Java 1.7 (or newer)

It cannot run on Android, as Android is Java 1.5.

Comment: Will this work nowadays that Android has some support for Java 1.7?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, it won't work on Android 4.2.2 because of `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet` even compiling with the latest Android Studio.